# Why can the waitpid system call only be used with child processes?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, system-calls, architecture

The man page `wait(2)` states that the `waitpid` system call returns the `ECHILD` error if the specified process is not a child of the calling process. Why is this? Would waiting on a non-child process create some sort of security issue? Is there a technical reason why implementing waiting on a non-child process would be difficult or impossible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of how `waitpid` works.  On a POSIX system, a signal (SIGCHLD) is delivered to a parent process when one of its child processes dies.  At a high level, all `waitpid` is doing is blocking until a SIGCHLD signal is delivered for the process (or one of the processes) specified.  You can't wait on arbitrary processes, because the SIGCHLD signal would never be delivered for them.

Answer (score 4):

godlygeek's answer is good for understanding how the system works but the subsequent question that inevitably follows is:

How to determine if a process has gone away?

The correct way to wait on a process in another process group or session is to use `kill()`.  Obviously, that is an unintuitive answer.  You can't use the `wait` family of functions because the SIGCHILD signal won't ever be passed to your process nor can you get the status code.  `kill()`, however, can tell you when a specific process has gone away by passing in 0 for the signal to send, which simply checks if a signal can be sent to the process.  The return value of `kill()` is complex but can be boiled down to this:  A value of 0 means the process is alive and would accept signals from your process while a value of -1 and errno EPERM means the process is alive but not accepting signals from your process.

Some sample C code that checks once per second to see if an arbitrary process is gone:

```
int res = kill(pid, 0);
while (res == 0 || (res < 0 && errno == EPERM))
{
    sleep(1);

    res = kill(pid, 0);
}
```

You can similarly experiment with the `kill` command:

```
kill -0 <pid>
```

That will pass pid and 0 into `kill()`.  Some shells have a built-in `kill`, so it's much more efficient than starting a new process (e.g. `ps`).

Comment: Note that your sample C code has a race condition: during the sleep, process `pid` could exit and then some process could run  `fork` and the new child be assigned that same pid.

Comment: True.  However, unless the process that starts is long-lived, it has a high probability of terminating shortly after it starts.  There isn't a way to wait on arbitrary processes to finish so the race condition is unavoidable.  It's also going to be rather rare as well to run into.  I don't see an alternative to using kill().